# return type string conflicts with function working

Tags: java, kotlin, return

here is my code:

```kotlin
class AddScenarioFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding:FragmentAddScenarioBinding
    private val arraylist = ArrayList<String>()

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_add_scenario, container, false)

        daysBg(binding.tvDayMon)
        daysBg(binding.tvDayTue)
        daysBg(binding.tvDayWed)
        daysBg(binding.tvDayThu)
        daysBg(binding.tvDayFri)
        daysBg(binding.tvDaySat)
        daysBg(binding.tvDaySun)

        return binding.root
    }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun daysBg(day_id:TextView): String {

        day_id.setOnClickListener {
            val buttonColor = day_id.background as ColorDrawable
            val color = buttonColor.color
            if (color == resources.getColor(android.R.color.transparent)) {
                day_id.setBackgroundTintList(resources.getColorStateList(R.color.app_primary));
                day_id.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white_light))
                arraylist.add(day_id.text.toString())
                for (i in arraylist)
                    when (i.length) {
                        0 -> binding.tvGetDays.text = resources.getString(R.string.never)
                        1 -> binding.tvGetDays.text = i
                        else -> binding.tvGetDays.text = "$i "
                    }
            }

            else if(color == resources.getColor(R.color.app_primary)){
                day_id.setBackgroundTintList(resources.getColorStateList(android.R.color.transparent));
                day_id.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.text_color))
                arraylist.remove(day_id.text.toString())
                for (i in arraylist)
                    when (i.length) {
                        0 -> binding.tvGetDays.text = resources.getString(R.string.never)
                        1 -> binding.tvGetDays.text = i
                        else -> binding.tvGetDays.text = "$i "
                    }
            }

        }
        for (i in arraylist)
        return i
    }
}
```

the function 'daysBg' is giving error and asking to remove explicitly return type 'string' from function. and if i do so my arraylist is not getting return it asks for unit return type.
i want to return in string please help with the code

Comment: What are you expecting for this to do: `for (i in arraylist) return i`?

Comment: You have three bizarre uses of for loops in your code. You might want to reread the documentation about what a for loop does to understand it better.

Comment: @Alex.T `for (i in arraylist)` is fetching the elements of arraylist, and and i am tringto return the arrylist from the function

Comment: so why not do `return arrayList`? Having the return in a loop, will just return the first element in the array (if there is one), since you can't return more than once from any function. Like Tenfour04, I suggest you do some reading.